# Get the object of an Observable and convert to Array with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, observable

Good Morning.

I am getting the following object and need to work with the data in the results (Array) but my my method does not working properly.

```
Object
currentPage: 1
firstRowOnPage: 1
lastRowOnPage: 6
pageCount: 1
pageSize: 10
results: Array(6)
0: {id: 1256, name: "Erik", address: "Centro", addressComplement: "Centro", cep: "11212-122", …}
1: {id: 1014, name: "Everson Luiz", address: null, addressComplement: null, cep: null, …}
2: {id: 1011, name: "Everson Luiz Silva", address: null, addressComplement: null, cep: null, …}
3: {id: 1284, name: "Fulado de Tal", address: null, addressComplement: null, cep: null, …}
4: {id: 1012, name: "Jackson Alexandre", address: null, addressComplement: null, cep: null, …}
5: {id: 1013, name: "Robson Henrique Silva", address: "", addressComplement: "", cep: "", …}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
rowCount: 6
__proto__: Object
```

When I try to access the data, I get an error stating that my object is not an array so it does not have the typical methods of an array like MAP and PUSH POP FILTER.

This is my object and this is my method.

```
  private dataStore = {
    treasurers: []
  };

  private loadAllTreasurers(): void {
    const unit = auth.getCurrentUnit();
    this.treasureService.getTreasurers(unit.id).subscribe((data: Treasurer[]) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.dataStore.treasurers = data;
    });
 }


<!--Service-->

 getTreasurers(unitId): Observable<Treasurer[]> {
    const url = '/treasury/treasurers/unit/' + unitId;
    return this.http
      .get<Treasurer[]>(url);
  }
```

I get the object from an AspnetCore 2.2 server

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your `Array` isn't the `data` object. It's in `data.results`. `data` looks like an object with pages response info. You want `data.results` and not the `data` object.

You should just need to update this:

```
this.treasureService.getTreasurers(unit.id).subscribe((data: object) => {
  console.log(data)
  this.dataStore.treasurers = data.results; // <-- .results
});
```

I'm not sure if your `data` object has a Type or not, so I set it to `object` as a placeholder

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for trying.

But it still doesn't run. The error persists in the DATA object. He tells me that he does not have the RESULT property.

I managed to solve it this wayI managed to solve this way using TAP:

```
this.treasurerService
      .getTreasurers(id)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => {                
            this.dataStore.treasurers = data.results;
          })
      );
```